# Bluetooth can't find any devices (Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS)

Tags: drivers, 22.04, bluetooth

I tried a lot of way to decide this problem, but it gave nothing to me.
It can't connect to any devices: my earphones and phone. But on Windows it works well.
I'm really a beginning user of Ubuntu. I'm sorry for my English straight away.
Some information from the commands:

```
    lsusb:

Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 13d3:5481 IMC Networks XiaoMi Webcam
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 30fa:0400  USB OPTICAL MOUSE 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0cb8:c549 Opticis Co., Ltd Bluetooth Radio
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub


dmesg | grep Blue:

[    1.300800] usb 1-3: Product: Bluetooth Radio
[    3.135721] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    3.135743] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    3.135748] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    3.135750] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    3.135753] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    3.313647] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    3.313651] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    3.313655] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   40.777477] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   40.777485] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   40.777488] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11


hciconfig -a:

hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 14:5A:FC:97:C3:76  ACL MTU: 1021:6  SCO MTU: 255:12
    UP RUNNING 
    RX bytes:2004 acl:0 sco:0 events:279 errors:0
    TX bytes:6517 acl:0 sco:0 commands:246 errors:0
    Features: 0xff 0xff 0xff 0xfe 0xdb 0xfd 0x7b 0x87
    Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
    Link policy: RSWITCH HOLD SNIFF PARK 
    Link mode: PERIPHERAL ACCEPT 
    Name: 'user-A7S'
    Class: 0x7c010c
    Service Classes: Rendering, Capturing, Object Transfer, Audio, Telephony
    Device Class: Computer, Laptop
    HCI Version: 5.2 (0xb)  Revision: 0xa
    LMP Version: 5.2 (0xb)  Subversion: 0x8852
    Manufacturer: Realtek Semiconductor Corporation (93)


dpkg -l | grep blue:

ii  blueman                                    2.2.4-1                                 amd64        Graphical bluetooth manager
ii  bluetooth                                  5.64-0ubuntu1                           all          Bluetooth support (metapackage)
ii  bluez                                      5.64-0ubuntu1                           amd64        Bluetooth tools and daemons
ii  bluez-cups                                 5.64-0ubuntu1                           amd64        Bluetooth printer driver for CUPS
ii  bluez-obexd                                5.64-0ubuntu1                           amd64        bluez obex daemon
ii  bluez-tools                                2.0~20170911.0.7cb788c-4                amd64        Set of tools to manage Bluetooth devices for linux
ii  gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-3.0:amd64            42.0-5                                  amd64        Introspection data for GnomeBluetooth
ii  gnome-bluetooth                            3.34.5-8                                amd64        GNOME Bluetooth Send To app
ii  gnome-bluetooth-3-common                   42.0-5                                  all          GNOME Bluetooth 3 common files
ii  gnome-bluetooth-common                     3.34.5-8                                all          GNOME Bluetooth common files
ii  libbluetooth3:amd64                        5.64-0ubuntu1                           amd64        Library to use the BlueZ Linux Bluetooth stack
ii  libgnome-bluetooth-3.0-13:amd64            42.0-5                                  amd64        GNOME Bluetooth 3 support library
ii  libgnome-bluetooth13:amd64                 3.34.5-8                                amd64        GNOME Bluetooth tools - support library
ii  pulseaudio-module-bluetooth                1:15.99.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu2                amd64        Bluetooth module for PulseAudio sound server


rfkill list:

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no


dmesg | grep usb:

[    0.321305] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.321305] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.321305] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    0.360380] pci 0000:05:00.4: quirk_usb_early_handoff+0x0/0x170 took 10940 usecs
[    0.865782] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002, bcdDevice= 5.19
[    0.865784] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    0.865785] usb usb1: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    0.865786] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 5.19.0-32-generic xhci-hcd
[    0.865786] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:05:00.3
[    0.866054] usb usb2: We don't know the algorithms for LPM for this host, disabling LPM.
[    0.866066] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003, bcdDevice= 5.19
[    0.866067] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    0.866068] usb usb2: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    0.866068] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 5.19.0-32-generic xhci-hcd
[    0.866069] usb usb2: SerialNumber: 0000:05:00.3
[    0.866621] usb usb3: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002, bcdDevice= 5.19
[    0.866622] usb usb3: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    0.866623] usb usb3: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    0.866623] usb usb3: Manufacturer: Linux 5.19.0-32-generic xhci-hcd
[    0.866624] usb usb3: SerialNumber: 0000:05:00.4
[    0.866806] usb usb4: We don't know the algorithms for LPM for this host, disabling LPM.
[    0.866817] usb usb4: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003, bcdDevice= 5.19
[    0.866818] usb usb4: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    0.866818] usb usb4: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    0.866819] usb usb4: Manufacturer: Linux 5.19.0-32-generic xhci-hcd
[    0.866820] usb usb4: SerialNumber: 0000:05:00.4
[    1.124116] usb 1-3: new full-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[    1.124136] usb 3-3: new high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[    1.300794] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=0cb8, idProduct=c549, bcdDevice= 0.00
[    1.300798] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    1.300800] usb 1-3: Product: Bluetooth Radio
[    1.300801] usb 1-3: Manufacturer: Realtek
[    1.300803] usb 1-3: SerialNumber: 00e04c000001
[    1.336519] usb 3-3: New USB device found, idVendor=13d3, idProduct=5481, bcdDevice=21.54
[    1.336523] usb 3-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    1.336525] usb 3-3: Product: XiaoMi Webcam
[    1.336526] usb 3-3: Manufacturer: Azurewave
[    1.336527] usb 3-3: SerialNumber: SunplusIT Inc
[    1.437457] usb 1-4: new low-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[    1.598330] usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=30fa, idProduct=0400, bcdDevice= 1.00
[    1.598335] usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[    1.598338] usb 1-4: Product: USB OPTICAL MOUSE 
[    1.618228] input: USB OPTICAL MOUSE  as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:05:00.3/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/0003:30FA:0400.0002/input/input9
[    1.618316] hid-generic 0003:30FA:0400.0002: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [USB OPTICAL MOUSE ] on usb-0000:05:00.3-4/input0
[    1.618357] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    1.618358] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    3.142150] usb 3-3: Found UVC 1.00 device XiaoMi Webcam (13d3:5481)
[    3.162020] input: XiaoMi Webcam: XiaoMi Webcam as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:05:00.4/usb3/3-3/3-3:1.0/input/input26
[    3.162100] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[    3.216063] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb


usb-devices:

T:  Bus=01 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=480 MxCh= 4
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0002 Rev=05.19
S:  Manufacturer=Linux 5.19.0-32-generic xhci-hcd
S:  Product=xHCI Host Controller
S:  SerialNumber=0000:05:00.3
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=03(Int.) MxPS=   4 Ivl=256ms

T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=02 Cnt=01 Dev#=  2 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 1.00 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0cb8 ProdID=c549 Rev=00.00
S:  Manufacturer=Realtek
S:  Product=Bluetooth Radio
S:  SerialNumber=00e04c000001
C:  #Ifs= 2 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=btusb
E:  Ad=02(O) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS=  64 Ivl=0ms
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=03(Int.) MxPS=  16 Ivl=1ms
E:  Ad=82(I) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS=  64 Ivl=0ms
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=btusb
E:  Ad=03(O) Atr=01(Isoc) MxPS=   0 Ivl=1ms
E:  Ad=83(I) Atr=01(Isoc) MxPS=   0 Ivl=1ms

T:  Bus=02 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=10000 MxCh= 2
D:  Ver= 3.10 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=03 MxPS= 9 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0003 Rev=05.19
S:  Manufacturer=Linux 5.19.0-32-generic xhci-hcd
S:  Product=xHCI Host Controller
S:  SerialNumber=0000:05:00.3
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=03(Int.) MxPS=   4 Ivl=256ms

T:  Bus=03 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=480 MxCh= 4
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0002 Rev=05.19
S:  Manufacturer=Linux 5.19.0-32-generic xhci-hcd
S:  Product=xHCI Host Controller
S:  SerialNumber=0000:05:00.4
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=03(Int.) MxPS=   4 Ivl=256ms

T:  Bus=03 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=02 Cnt=01 Dev#=  2 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.01 Cls=ef(misc ) Sub=02 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=13d3 ProdID=5481 Rev=21.54
S:  Manufacturer=Azurewave
S:  Product=XiaoMi Webcam
S:  SerialNumber=SunplusIT Inc
C:  #Ifs= 2 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=0e(video) Sub=01 Prot=00 Driver=uvcvideo
E:  Ad=87(I) Atr=03(Int.) MxPS=  16 Ivl=16ms
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=0e(video) Sub=02 Prot=00 Driver=uvcvideo

T:  Bus=04 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=10000 MxCh= 2
D:  Ver= 3.10 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=03 MxPS= 9 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0003 Rev=05.19
S:  Manufacturer=Linux 5.19.0-32-generic xhci-hcd
S:  Product=xHCI Host Controller
S:  SerialNumber=0000:05:00.4
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=03(Int.) MxPS=   4 Ivl=256ms


dmesg | grep hci:

[    0.655656] ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
[    0.655660] ehci-pci: EHCI PCI platform driver
[    0.655668] ehci-platform: EHCI generic platform driver
[    0.655672] ohci_hcd: USB 1.1 'Open' Host Controller (OHCI) Driver
[    0.655674] ohci-pci: OHCI PCI platform driver
[    0.655679] ohci-platform: OHCI generic platform driver
[    0.655683] uhci_hcd: USB Universal Host Controller Interface driver
[    0.865369] ahci 0000:06:00.0: version 3.0
[    0.865383] xhci_hcd 0000:05:00.3: xHCI Host Controller
[    0.865388] xhci_hcd 0000:05:00.3: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    0.865471] xhci_hcd 0000:05:00.3: hcc params 0x0268ffe5 hci version 0x110 quirks 0x0000020000000410
[    0.865488] ahci 0000:06:00.0: AHCI 0001.0301 32 slots 1 ports 6 Gbps 0x1 impl SATA mode
[    0.865490] ahci 0000:06:00.0: flags: 64bit ncq sntf ilck pm led clo only pmp fbs pio slum part 
[    0.865652] scsi host0: ahci
[    0.865753] xhci_hcd 0000:05:00.3: xHCI Host Controller
[    0.865755] xhci_hcd 0000:05:00.3: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 2
[    0.865757] xhci_hcd 0000:05:00.3: Host supports USB 3.1 Enhanced SuperSpeed
[    0.865786] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 5.19.0-32-generic xhci-hcd
[    0.865810] ahci 0000:06:00.1: AHCI 0001.0301 32 slots 1 ports 6 Gbps 0x1 impl SATA mode
[    0.865812] ahci 0000:06:00.1: flags: 64bit ncq sntf ilck pm led clo only pmp fbs pio slum part 
[    0.865925] scsi host1: ahci
[    0.866068] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 5.19.0-32-generic xhci-hcd
[    0.866285] xhci_hcd 0000:05:00.4: xHCI Host Controller
[    0.866288] xhci_hcd 0000:05:00.4: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 3
[    0.866367] xhci_hcd 0000:05:00.4: hcc params 0x0268ffe5 hci version 0x110 quirks 0x0000020000000410
[    0.866599] xhci_hcd 0000:05:00.4: xHCI Host Controller
[    0.866601] xhci_hcd 0000:05:00.4: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 4
[    0.866602] xhci_hcd 0000:05:00.4: Host supports USB 3.1 Enhanced SuperSpeed
[    0.866623] usb usb3: Manufacturer: Linux 5.19.0-32-generic xhci-hcd
[    0.866819] usb usb4: Manufacturer: Linux 5.19.0-32-generic xhci-hcd
[    1.124116] usb 1-3: new full-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[    1.124136] usb 3-3: new high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[    1.437457] usb 1-4: new low-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd


lsmod | grep btusb:

btusb                  61440  0
btrtl                  24576  1 btusb
btbcm                  24576  1 btusb
btintel                40960  1 btusb
btmtk                  16384  1 btusb
bluetooth             827392  44 btrtl,btmtk,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb,rfcomm


lsmod:

Module                  Size  Used by
rfcomm                 86016  16
ccm                    20480  6
cmac                   16384  3
algif_hash             16384  1
algif_skcipher         16384  1
af_alg                 32768  6 algif_hash,algif_skcipher
bnep                   28672  2
btusb                  61440  0
btrtl                  24576  1 btusb
btbcm                  24576  1 btusb
uvcvideo              114688  0
btintel                40960  1 btusb
videobuf2_vmalloc      20480  1 uvcvideo
btmtk                  16384  1 btusb
videobuf2_memops       20480  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_v4l2         32768  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_common       81920  4 videobuf2_vmalloc,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_memops
bluetooth             827392  44 btrtl,btmtk,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb,rfcomm
videodev              274432  3 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
ecdh_generic           16384  2 bluetooth
mc                     65536  4 videodev,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
ecc                    40960  1 ecdh_generic
snd_ctl_led            24576  0
intel_rapl_msr         20480  0
intel_rapl_common      40960  1 intel_rapl_msr
snd_soc_dmic           16384  1
snd_acp3x_pdm_dma      16384  1
snd_acp3x_rn           16384  1
snd_hda_codec_realtek   163840  1
joydev                 32768  0
rtw89_8852ae           16384  0
snd_hda_codec_generic   102400  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
edac_mce_amd           36864  0
snd_sof_amd_renoir     16384  0
ledtrig_audio          16384  2 snd_ctl_led,snd_hda_codec_generic
rtw89_8852a           712704  1 rtw89_8852ae
snd_sof_amd_acp        45056  1 snd_sof_amd_renoir
snd_sof_pci            24576  1 snd_sof_amd_renoir
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     81920  2
snd_sof               208896  3 snd_sof_amd_acp,snd_sof_pci,snd_sof_amd_renoir
rtw89_pci              61440  1 rtw89_8852ae
nouveau              2367488  3
snd_hda_intel          53248  8
snd_sof_utils          20480  1 snd_sof
kvm_amd               167936  0
snd_intel_dspcfg       36864  1 snd_hda_intel
snd_intel_sdw_acpi     20480  1 snd_intel_dspcfg
rtw89_core            405504  2 rtw89_pci,rtw89_8852a
snd_soc_core          368640  4 snd_acp3x_rn,snd_sof,snd_soc_dmic,snd_acp3x_pdm_dma
binfmt_misc            24576  1
mxm_wmi                16384  1 nouveau
snd_hda_codec         176128  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_compress           24576  1 snd_soc_core
kvm                  1130496  1 kvm_amd
drm_ttm_helper         16384  1 nouveau
snd_hda_core          114688  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek
ac97_bus               16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_pcm_dmaengine      20480  1 snd_soc_core
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
ttm                    98304  2 drm_ttm_helper,nouveau
mac80211             1314816  2 rtw89_core,rtw89_pci
snd_pci_ps             20480  0
snd_seq_midi           20480  0
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  1
snd_acp_pci            16384  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
drm_display_helper    184320  1 nouveau
snd_pci_acp6x          20480  0
aesni_intel           376832  8
snd_rawmidi            45056  1 snd_seq_midi
cec                    81920  1 drm_display_helper
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
snd_seq                77824  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
cryptd                 24576  3 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel
rc_core                65536  1 cec
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
snd_pcm               155648  13 snd_sof_amd_acp,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pci_acp6x,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_sof,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_sof_utils,snd_hda_core,snd_acp3x_pdm_dma,snd_pci_ps,snd_pcm_dmaengine
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
rapl                   20480  0
drm_kms_helper        200704  2 drm_display_helper,nouveau
input_leds             16384  0
snd_timer              40960  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 nouveau
cfg80211             1044480  3 rtw89_core,mac80211,rtw89_8852a
serio_raw              20480  0
snd_pci_acp5x          20480  0
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
hid_multitouch         32768  0
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
snd_rn_pci_acp3x       20480  0
snd                   114688  33 snd_ctl_led,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_sof,snd_timer,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
wmi_bmof               16384  0
sysfillrect            20480  1 drm_kms_helper
snd_acp_config         16384  3 snd_rn_pci_acp3x,snd_acp_pci,snd_sof_amd_renoir
sysimgblt              20480  1 drm_kms_helper
snd_soc_acpi           16384  2 snd_acp_config,snd_sof_amd_renoir
soundcore              16384  2 snd_ctl_led,snd
k10temp                16384  0
libarc4                16384  1 mac80211
ucsi_acpi              16384  0
snd_pci_acp3x          20480  0
ccp                   110592  1 kvm_amd
typec_ucsi             49152  1 ucsi_acpi
typec                  73728  1 typec_ucsi
mac_hid                16384  0
sch_fq_codel           24576  2
msr                    16384  0
parport_pc             53248  0
ppdev                  24576  0
lp                     28672  0
parport                73728  3 parport_pc,lp,ppdev
ramoops                32768  0
drm                   581632  8 drm_kms_helper,drm_display_helper,drm_ttm_helper,ttm,nouveau
pstore_blk             16384  0
reed_solomon           28672  1 ramoops
pstore_zone            32768  1 pstore_blk
efi_pstore             16384  0
ip_tables              32768  0
x_tables               57344  1 ip_tables
autofs4                45056  2
usbhid                 65536  0
r8169                 102400  0
nvme                   49152  2
hid_generic            16384  0
ahci                   49152  0
xhci_pci               24576  0
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
nvme_core             147456  3 nvme
i2c_piix4              32768  0
libahci                49152  1 ahci
xhci_pci_renesas       20480  1 xhci_pci
realtek                32768  1
i2c_hid_acpi           16384  0
i2c_hid                36864  1 i2c_hid_acpi
video                  65536  1 nouveau
hid                   159744  4 i2c_hid,usbhid,hid_multitouch,hid_generic
wmi                    32768  3 wmi_bmof,mxm_wmi,nouveau


lspci:

00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne Root Complex
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne IOMMU
00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:01.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe GPP Bridge
00:01.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge
00:01.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:02.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge
00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Internal PCIe GPP Bridge to Bus
00:08.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Internal PCIe GPP Bridge to Bus
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 51)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 5
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 6
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Cezanne Data Fabric; Function 7
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GA106M [GeForce RTX 3060 Mobile / Max-Q] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 228e (rev a1)
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8852AE 802.11ax PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
04:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller 980
05:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Zeppelin/Raven/Raven2 PCIe Dummy Function (rev c5)
05:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Renoir Radeon High Definition Audio Controller
05:00.2 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) Platform Security Processor
05:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne USB 3.1
05:00.4 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne USB 3.1
05:00.5 Multimedia controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor (rev 01)
05:00.6 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller
06:00.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 81)
06:00.1 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 81)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a commit in the upstream kernel that may fix this.  In terminal check `mokutil --sb` as Secure Boot will need to be disabled.  Then

```
sudo apt install git dkms
git clone https://github.com/jeremyb31/bluetooth-5.19.git
sudo dkms add bluetooth-5.19
sudo dkms install btusb/4.0
```

Reboot and test

Comment: Many thanks! Now it works and i'm happy because now I don't have to return to Windows.

Comment: I have Ubuntu 22.04.3.   This did not work for me.   I get: robert@n7110:~/workspace/bluetooth-6.2$ git clone https://github.com/jeremyb31/bluetooth-5.19.git
sudo dkms add bluetooth-5.19
sudo dkms install btusb/4.0
...
Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel. Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area...
'make' all KVER=5.15.0-91-generic...(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for btusb: 4.0 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.15.0-91-generic (x86_64)